# HttpNetty ApacheBench test: apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)

Tags: netty

I have a simple HttpServer application based on netty framework. I'm trying to test it with apache bench tool (OS Windows 7) but I always get an error:

> The timeout specified has expired (70007)

I've tried to use different queries in order to run test - it doesn't help. At the same time I get a response from  server if I access it from browser. Did anyone experience the same problem?

Comment: For those who face this with spring 5 netty, there's a bug filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14964

Comment: There's and alternative tool which is called Siege. It worked with spring boot 2 spring framework 5 with netty in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could come from several things. But my guess is, ApacheBench is just too "muscly" for your infrastructure, or at least your configuration. Here are a couple things you can try:

**Client side**

- Try looking at the concurrency level used from your ApacheBench and lowering it

**Server side**

- You may have limits on the number of tcp ports available. You can change it by changing the first port available `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.portrange.first=32768`. This will lower the first port number available for tcp and therefore increase the total number of ports available.
- you can try lowering the time wait number  `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.msl=1000`. Beware that this is just for testing as it would mean in production that client would timeout very quickly.